# Strange facebook "like" widget counter behaviour

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, facebook-like

I've added on [my wordpress site](http://vod.io/?page_id=7) facebook like buttons in a bunch of places.
The strangest behaviour happens for all my posts under the "blog" page template.
All my posts seem to have the same overblown counter (currently counting 199)

More than that, even on facebook "[Like Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)" widget page, for every url I type facebook shows me that same strange overblown counter.

**You can see for yourself at:**
  http://vod.io/?page_id=7 - all posts have a 199 counter.
  http://vod.io/?p=141 - single post has a 199 counter.

On facebook: developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
typing directly http://vod.io/?p=141 will show that that page has a **199 counter**

The actual code (wp php) for the "like" link:

```
    <div class="simplesocialbutton ssb-button-fblike">
    <!-- Facebook like--><div id="fb-root"></div>
    <fb:like href="http://vod.io/?p=<?php the_ID(); ?>" send="false" layout="button_count" width="100" show_faces="false" action="like" font="">
    </fb:like>
```

I've been straggeling with this for a while, but can't find any solution.

Comment: Seams to work now? was it the same og:url problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because all your pages set the `og:url` to `http://vod.io//` (with double slash). `og:url` is a way of overriding what URL Facebook should use in the graph for the current page, known as the "Canonical URL". If you use the [Facebook debugger on the ?p=141 page](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fvod.io%2F%3Fp%3D141) you see "URL for Likes: http://vod.io//" and same like URL for [?p=144 page](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fvod.io%2F%3Fp%3D144).

Solution is to provide proper `og:url` content for all pages or skip them and let Facebook infer the content by using the page URL.

But one mystery why Facebook thinks that the [start page](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fvod.io%2F) should have `http://vod.io/` (without double slash) as Canonical URL despite that `og:url` is provided with double slashes, maybe some kind of URL normalizaton? and I have no idea where the 199 likes comes from, if you look in [the graph is says 4 likes for double slash](http://graph.facebook.com/http://vod.io//) at the moment and [22 "shares" for single slash](http://graph.facebook.com/http://vod.io/). Maybe the warning about redirect loop in the debugger is a hint?

Hope this helps.